# MAUI Syncfusion ListView How to set busy indicator color?

Tags: maui, syncfusion, indicator

I'm using Syncfusion's SfListView in my MAUI app.
While lazy loading a busy indicator is shown.
How can I set the color of the loading indicator?

```xml
<listView:SfListView Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"
                     x:Name="ListView"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding Results}"
                     AutoFitMode="Height"
                     LoadMoreOption="Auto"
                     LoadMoreCommand="{Binding LoadMoreItemsCommand}"
                     LoadMoreCommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference ListView}}"
                     IsVisible="{Binding IsAvailable}" >

    <listView:SfListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="contracts:MyDto">
                <VerticalStackLayout Margin="0,0,0,30">

                    <VerticalStackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewModels:MyViewModel}}, Path=TapEntryCommand}"
                                              CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                    </VerticalStackLayout.GestureRecognizers>

                    <HorizontalStackLayout>
                        <Label Text="(" />
                        <Label Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat='{0:dd.MM.yyyy}'}" />
                        <Label Text=")" />
                    </HorizontalStackLayout>

                </VerticalStackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </listView:SfListView.ItemTemplate>

</listView:SfListView>
```

Comment: Where is the busy indicator?

Comment: @Julian The indicator is shown an the bottom of the SfListView while loading more data.

Comment: So you didn't add any SfBusyIndicator instance yourself?

Comment: @Julian Nope, it is the indicator out of the SfListView -box.

Comment: According to the docs, you can set a [custom LoadMoreTemplate](https://help.syncfusion.com/maui/listview/loadmore?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=xaml#loading-indicator). It doesn't say anything about customizing the indicator color. I would expect that it uses the primary color or a system color for this.

Comment: @Julian Unfortunately it is not using the primary color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works using the DataTemplate...

```xml
<listView:SfListView Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"
                     x:Name="ListView"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding Results}"
                     AutoFitMode="Height"
                     LoadMoreOption="Auto"
                     LoadMoreCommand="{Binding LoadMoreItemsCommand}"
                     LoadMoreCommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference ListView}}"
                     IsVisible="{Binding IsAvailable}" >
    <listView:SfListView.LoadMoreTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <listView:ListViewLoadMoreIndicator
                IsRunning="{Binding IsLazyLoading, Source={x:Reference Name=ListView}}"
                IsVisible="{Binding IsLazyLoading, Source={x:Reference Name=ListView}}" 
                Color="{StaticResource PrimaryColor}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </listView:SfListView.LoadMoreTemplate>
```